# Light box style Model dialog in C# windows form

Tags: c#, windows

I want to show jquery lightbox style model dialog in c# windows form. My dialog box will appear from the MDI child form button's Click event.How I do that ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is to mask the parent form, then there is no simple way to do this afaik, what I've done is create a transparent form on top of the parent and then open another custom form as a dialog on top of the fake mask window.

something like this, where `window` is your popup and `owner` the form that is going to be masked:

```
Mask = new LayerWindow();
Mask.Show(owner);
window.Show(Mask);
```

this is what I'm using as a mask:

```
public class LayerWindow : Form
{
    public LayerWindow()
    {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        TransparencyKey = Color.Fuchsia;
        base.BackColor = Color.Black;
        Opacity = 0.50;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }

    public void Show(Control parent)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("No parent provided");

        var container = parent.FindForm();
        if (container == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("No parent Form found. Make sure that the control is contained in a form before showing a popup.");

        Location = PointToScreen(container.Location);
        Bounds = container.Bounds;

        Owner = container;
        Owner.Enabled = false;

        base.Show(container);
    }

    public void Unmask()
    {
        if (Owner != null)
            Owner.Enabled = true;

        Hide();
    }
```